# Login to Magento Admin Panel is Acting Quirky

Tags: php, magento

I setup a Magneto installation (1.9.1 CE) today in a production environment. Everything seems to be working fine, but when I log into the backend, my password doesn't work. When I keep trying it, ultimately it works. But it doesn't work every time. What is the reason that Magento is acting quirky like this? If I typed in the correct password, shouldn't it work every time?

EDIT: This works fine in Firefox; the problem is only in Chrome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please try to in mozila browser, some time issue in crome browser

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. I made an edit to the question, noting that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the cookie on your browser created by magento. Delete the cookie first before logging in. Its a bug of magento 1.8+